# Acces Form Properties from UserControls

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

Is there's a way to acces Main Form Properties like (Opacity, Top Most, BackColor, etc)
from Button in User Control

i've tried this but didnt work

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.TopMost = true;
        frm1.Opacity = 50 %;
    }
```

Comment: [UserControl.ParentForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform) or [Control.FindForm()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.findform) (same thing) or [Control.TopLevelControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.toplevelcontrol) (dependable). -- When you do this: `Form1 frm1 = new Form1();` you create a new instance of a Form that has nothing to do with the instance of the Form that's hosting your UC.

Comment: Obviously it's possible, given the comments and answers so far.  In general, though, it's a bad design for a child control to directly modify its parent.  Instead, have the UserControl raise a custom EVENT that the parent form subscribes to.  When the event is received the parent form can update itself.  This theoretically makes the UserControl more re-usable since it can be used in a different form with no changes required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Application.OpenForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=net-5.0) array to access any open form:

```
Application.OpenForms[0].Text = "Hello";
```

or, a better way:

```
public static T GetForm<T>()
{
    foreach(object f in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (f is T) return (T) f;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Example to access Form1 using this method:

```
GetForm<Form1>().Text = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`Control.FindForm Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.findform?view=net-5.0) to get the form that the control is on.

And generally use decimals between 0-1 to assign `Opacity`.

```
private void btnInUserControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = this.FindForm() as Form1;
    form1.Opacity = .5;
    form1.TopMost = true;
}
```